# Save variable in a line starting from a specific point

Tags: c#, regex

A C#-program scans a large .txt-file for a specific pattern, e. g. processID. If it finds this pattern, it shall write the following ID into a variable.

I'm using `StreamReader` and the method `ReadLine` to scan each line separately.
My question is how do I save the value if `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(line, processID)` is true until a certain point?

This is the code so far:

```
String path = "C:\\Users\\myfile.txt", line = null, getID = null, ram = null;

String IDPattern = "^\\d{5}-\\d{6}$";
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@path);

while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if(line.Contains("--Process-ID="))
    {

        // ram = How does ram gets the value?!

        if(getID != ram)
        {
            getID = ram;
            Console.WriteLine(getID);
        }
    }
}
```

The variable `ram` is used to save a value temporarely and to compare it with `getID`.

Comment: Wellcome to stackoverflow community. Please, share your work, what do you tried until now? What code have you written? Try to be more specific

Comment: "..how do I save the value.." Where do you want to save it? In memory? In a file? In database? In the cloud? ....

Comment: Regex is a memory heavy object. In your scenario you should declare a new Regex object with the pattern and reuse it in every line `Regex myRegex = new Regex("pattern");` ... `myRegex.Match(line);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use capture groups. Try this code

```
var regex = new Regex("--Process-ID=(?<id>\\d{5}-\\d{6})");
string processID;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("C:\\Users\\myfile.txt")))
{
    while (true)
    {
        var nextLine = reader.ReadLine();
        if (nextLine == null)
            break;

        var match = regex.Match(nextLine);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            processID = match.Groups["id"].Value;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

When regex find first match it will save it to local variable and skip rest of file.

Comment: What does (?<id>) stands for? Is it the group you are referring to in line 14? And how do I save text, e. g. an e-mail-address which follows the next line after processID has occured?

Comment: @Linus yes, this is group name. To save some text in next line you should modify last `if`. Also you may need another regex to extract email from text

Comment: @Linus It is the sintax of a named group `(?<groupName>pattern)`

Comment: @AleksAndreev I've declared another regex to extract the e-mail, however, the result is not displayed by `Console.WriteLine`. Do I need a special escape sequence, etc.?

Comment: @Linus  I can't tell what wrong with your second regex without seeing it. However it's looks like another question

Answer (score 0):

you can use File class and use something like this to achieve your goal.

```
 IList<string> text = new List<string>() { "pid456","Pid 123" }; //Place your pid here
 var endTag = "xyz"; //end tag of tag file or EOF

            IList<string> log = File.ReadAllLines(file).ToList<string>();

            for (int i = log.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                if (text.Any(t => log[i].Contains(t)))
                {
                   var PID= log[i];
                }

                if (log[i].Contains(endTag))
                {
                    break;
                }
             }
```

Comment: This is not much pattern (Regex) related